# hover color for .prepend and .append "parent" element of "child" element

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, menu

Hi am working on this menu run code snippet :)

my problem is I can´t get the drop down arrows: hover color to work as I want.
Ex.
If I hover over the -> "Level 1b" -> "Level 1b 2b" -> "Level 1b 2b 3b"
then the arrows on the "level 1b", "level 1b 2b" should be white and the rest black

can somebody please help me

https://jsfiddle.net/BugiBH/xLumg78x/

```js
/* 
 * add theme-features
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('a[target="_blank"]').addClass("target-blank");
    $('.top-nav  a, .main-navigation  a').prepend("<div id='before' style='float: left;'></div>");
    $('.top-nav  a, .main-navigation  a').append("<div id='after' style='float: right;'></div>");

});
```

```css
nav {
    background: blue;
    margin-top 5px;
}
/*Menu placering*/
 #site-nav-container {
    text-align: center;
}
#site-nav-container, #site-nav-container ul {
    z-index: 10;
}
#site-navigation {
    display: inline-block;
}
#site-navigation li {
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: left;
}
/*hover*/
 .main-navigation ul li:hover, .main-navigation ul li.current-menu-item, .main-navigation ul li.current-page-ancestor {
    border-top: 2px solid white;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li:hover, .main-navigation ul ul li.current-menu-item, .main-navigation ul ul li.current-page-ancestor {
    border-top: 0px;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover #after, .main-navigation ul ul li:hover #after {
    color: white;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
/*level one*/
 .main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
}
.main-navigation ul li {
    float: left;
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
}
.main-navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*inline-box-align: initial;*/
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a #after:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:" \f13a";
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.main-navigation #target-blank {
    display: flex;
}
/*level two*/
 .main-navigation ul ul {
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 2px solid blue;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-top: 0px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li a {
    color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
.main-navigation ul li .menu-item-has-children > a #after:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:" \f138";
}
/*level higher than two*/
 .main-navigation ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top:0;
}
.target-blank:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:" \f08e ";
    font-size: 70%;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.top-nav #target-blank {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
        <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1729"> <a target="_blank" href="#" class="target-blank">Level 1a</a>

            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1733"> <a href="#">Level 1b</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1765"> <a target="_blank" href="#" class="target-blank">Level 1b 2a</a>

                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1766"> <a target="_blank" href="#" class="target-blank">Level 1b 2a 3a</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1730"> <a target="_blank" href="#" class="target-blank">Level 1b 2b</a>

                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1751"> <a target="_blank" href="#" class="target-blank">Level 1b 2b 3a</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1753"> <a target="_blank" href="#" class="target-blank">Level 1b 2b 3b</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1762">
                        <a target="_blank" href="#" class="target-blank">Level 1b 2c</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1728"> <a target="_blank" href="#" class="target-blank">Level 1c</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1732"> <a target="_blank" href="#" class="target-blank">level 1c 1a </a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: 'the rest' are the arrows in others menu items? Because seems to work fine.

Comment: You're asking how to change the the color _only_ of the arrows? Not including the color of the menu item?

Comment: it would like to act like the wide border above and to the left of the menu item

so if I hover over the menu item "Level 1b 2b 3b". then the arrow on the menu item
"Level 1b 2a" and "Level 1b 2c" must remain black and not white as they do now

Comment: please see the picture in the comment in answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the parent selector ( `>` ), so hovering the first li, would make every `#after` inside your nav take the changes.

Remove your current CSS regarding `li:hover` and add this 1-liner:

```
#primary-menu > li:hover > a > #after, #primary-menu > li > ul > li:hover > a > #after  {
    color: white;
}
```

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/xLumg78x/2/)

```
#primary-menu > li
```

Selects all < li >s where the parent is an element with id `#primary-menu`

```
#primary-menu > li:hover > a > #after { /*somecss*/ }
```

Selects all elements with ID `#after` that has a parent `< a >` with a parent `< li >`:hover (apply `/*somecss*/` only when **THIS** li is being hovered)

For further reference check [**CSS Selectors**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: I have looked at your jsFiddle.
it still does not really work as I want.

maybe I'm bad to explain what I want

I made a picture of how it should look like
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tn9yw26nomqy9dp/menu%20hover%20arow.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I understand now, please look at the fiddle again, I think thats what you want to achieve.

Comment: I kept the :hover on the li element, but specified that hovering a li, would affect only the immediate children a element, and not all a elements with the CSS selector '>' !

Comment: I will add some explanation on the answer, code on the comments is not easy to read

Answer (score 0):

update some of Css and its working for me

```
.main-navigation ul > li:hover #after{
    color: white;
}
.main-navigation ul > li:hover .sub-menu #after{
    color: black;
}
.main-navigation ul > li:hover .sub-menu li:hover #after{
    color: white;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
}
```